# How to create an eloquent model with a database function as source?

Tags: php, postgresql, eloquent, model

Some background information:

The Model to create is for an existing [partitioned](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-partitioning.html) table in a postgresql database. Cause of performance issues it is not ideal to request the parent table. We created a custom database function to get the data from the child tables and connect the result by union all depending on a parameter. The data for the parameter is defined by the user permission, so the ids are known when the Model is created. The logic behind relies heavily on Models and relation so raw queries would cause big trouble.

Currently I use the parent-table to get the data but the request take 2-3 Seconds. When the child tables are called, the result is below 100 ms. So I need a possibility to get data from multiple the child-tables.

To the question:

How to set the existing function as base for the Model?

I've tried to put the function name in DB::raw, but the function is still escaped: `SELECT *FROM "partionedTableTestGetData(1,2,3)"`. I need the function used as data source for the model. The function queries the child tables direct and uses a union all to build the result set.

Writing to this model isn't needed.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public static function boot()
{
    $oUser = Auth::user();
    $aIds = $oUser->getCustomIds();
    //some sanitation here
    $this->table = DB::raw('partionedTableTestGetData('.implode(',', $aIds ).')';
    static::addGlobalScope(new CustomScope('id-field'));
}
```

Database schema of the table:

```
- public.parent_table -> parent table
- parent_table.parent_table_123 -> child table of parent_table with all data of company with id 123
- parent_table.parent_table_321 -> child table of parent_table with all data of company with id 321
... about 600 other tables like  this ...
```

The following function is used to fetch  the child_table data:

```sql
create function partionedTableTestGetData(companyids text) returns SETOF parent_table
    language plpgsql
as $$
DECLARE
  aiIDs BIGINT[];
  iID BIGINT;
  sSql TEXT;
  sSqlCondition TEXT;
  bFirst BOOLEAN;
  bParent BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  bFirst = TRUE ;
  bParent = FALSE ;
  aiIDs = string_to_array(sSzenarioIDs, ',');
  sSql = '';
  sSqlCondition = '';

  FOREACH iID IN ARRAY aiIDs
  LOOP
    IF EXISTS (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='parent_table' || iID AND table_schema = 'parent_table')
    THEN
      IF bFirst IS FALSE
      THEN
        sSql = sSql || ' UNION ALL ';
      END IF;
      bFirst = FALSE;
      sSql = sSql || format('SELECT * FROM parent_table.parent_table_%s %s', iID, sSqlCondition);
    ELSE bParent = TRUE;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  IF bParent IS TRUE OR sSql = ''
  THEN
    IF bFirst IS FALSE
    THEN
      sSql = sSql || ' UNION ALL ';
    END IF;
    bFirst = FALSE;
    sSql = sSql || format('SELECT * FROM ONLY public.parent_table %s', sSqlCondition);
  END IF;
  RAISE NOTICE '%', sSql;

  IF sSql <> ''
  THEN RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sSql;
  END IF;

  RETURN;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Woudln't it be easier to create an actual second table with your function (e.g. with database triggers to keep it in sync) and just use the second table as a data source in Eloquent as you would with any table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I think you suggest to create a sort of cache table for the data. Problem is the used IDs depend on the user permission. So I would have to crate a own table set for every user and create it new if the permissions are modified. That would be too complicated.

How too deal with the parameters?

Comment: Yes that is what I am suggesting. Can you not just add the user-id / "custom-ids" to the datasets in the - as you put it - cache table and have your application code only let the user access the records that he should have access to? I know this does not really answer your question, my point is just that it might be thought too complex

Comment: Accessing data is a performance problem. The DB has to search through all child tables. The custom I'd is in the table. 
Only option I could think of is creating a custom model which crates union all queries

Comment: Have you added indexes for the attributes you are querying by? Sounds kind of weird that a function would yield quicker results than a query. Even more so if you not(!) have interim caches in place (like other tables). Could you possibly add your database schema to the question so we can go from there?

Comment: Indexes are optimized (combined keys where needed). I've updated the question for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Although it feels like the cache tables are the preferred way of handling this issue. This should solve your problem.

```
$items = \DB::connection()->select(
      'SELECT * FROM partionedTableTestGetData(:ids)',
      ['ids' => implode(',', $aIds)]
);
```

If you would want a Eloquent model to be hydrated by the data that was fetched via the query you could use something like this:

```
Model::hydrate($items)->all() // returns Model[]
```

Comment: Tank you for this answer. Problem is each model has a global scope for permission check. They contain some joins and wheres. I do not want to replicate the Logic.
Is there a way to apply scopes to this solution?

Comment: No, in this scenario it's not possible to use the Eloquent scope for query filtering. This is because the starting point is the raw query instead of the Elquent model. Joins and such from relations on the model do work as usual.